# Session expiration issue in Laravel 5

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel-5

Users can sign in successfully using Auth::attempt() function but the problem is, the user details randomly get expired when different pages are visited. Auth::check() function has been used to check whether any user has signed in or not. Also, after logging out, if the backspace button of the browser is pressed, it browses the page viewed by the user previously, that means the previous session doesn't get destroyed. I'm using Laravel version 5 and PHP version 5.6.11.

If anyone else faced the same problem, then please provide any suggestion. Thank You :)

Here is my logout function:

```
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        return Redirect::route('login');

    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::route('login');
    }
```

Comment: Just a comment, I don't think you need Session::flush(). The docs says 'To log users out of your application, you may use the logout method on the Auth facade. This will clear the authentication information in the user's session:'